# Javascript ! and !! differences

Tags: javascript, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the !! operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript)

What is the difference between these two operators? Does !! have special meaning, or does it simply mean you are doing two '!' operations. I know there are "Truth" and "Truthy" concepts in Javascript, but I'm not sure if !! is meant for "Truth"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing `!!` is a common way of converting a "truthy" or "falsey" variable into a *genuine* boolean value.

For example:

```
var foo = null;

if (!!foo === true) {
    // Code if foo was "truthy"
}
```

After the first `!` is applied to `foo`, the value returned is `true`. Notting that value again makes it `false`, meaning the code inside the `if` block is not entered.

Comment: @For clarity, perhaps "into a *genuine* boolean value". `!!0` is, of course, a *false* boolean value...

Comment: So why not just do `if(foo) {}`? Wouldn't this also do the same?

Comment: @Robert: Yes it would. I should probably make it `if(!!foo === true)`

Comment: @Robert: In this case you don't need the `!!`. But it is handy whenever you need a real boolean representation of some value.

Answer (score 8):

!! is just double !

```
!true // -> false
!!true // -> true
```

!! is a common way to cast something to boolean value

```
!!{}  // -> true
!!null // -> false
```